# Fire validation on UI with more than one active products with same name

Tags: trigger, validation

I have an active checkbox field in the standard product object. I want to throw a validation on UI if the user tries to activate a product if there is already a product with the same name and is already active.

I don't want to use Trigger. Can this be achieved any other way and how?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an on-update Flow with a Get Records element to check for any other Products with the Name. If you add a checkbox "Duplicates" to your Product and a Validation Rule that checks for "Duplicates"=TRUE, your Flow can stop the activation.